# Danskins' theorem

Tags: convex-analysis

Suppose $\phi (x,z)$ is a continuous function of two arguments,

$$\phi :{\mathbb {R} }^{n}\times Z\rightarrow {\mathbb {R} }$$

where 
$Z\subset {\mathbb {R} }^{m}$
is a compact set. Further assume that 
$ \phi (x,z)$
is convex in $x$ for every $z\in Z$.

Define
$$f(x)=\max _{z\in Z}\phi (x,z)$$

and

$$Z_{0}(x)=\left\{{\overline {z}}:\phi (x,{\overline {z}})=\max _{z\in Z}\phi (x,z)\right\}.$$

Danskin's theorem: $f(x)$ is differentiable at $x$ if $Z_{0}(x)$ consists of a single element $\overline {z}$. Furthermore, the derivative of $f(x)$ is given by
$$ {\frac {\partial f}{\partial x}}={\frac {\partial \phi (x,{\overline {z}})}{\partial x}}.$$

Taken from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danskin%27s_theorem#Statement)

**My question**: When evaluating $\frac {\partial \phi (x,{\overline {z}})}{\partial x}$ at a given $x$, is $\overline z$ is to be treated as a constant or as a function of $x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\bar{z}$ is a constant for the purposes of the partial derivative.  In fact, the points $\bar{z}$ are just the points where $\phi(x,z)$ attains its maximum on the set $Z$ so you could, if it makes things clearer, write the partial derivative as
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial \phi(x,z)}{\partial x}{\left| _{z\in Z_0}\right.} $$

The set $Z_0$ does not depend on $x$ in particular.